# Changing the inner tags class of a tag using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<li id="toto" class="jstree-leaf">
    <ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a class=""><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>Story B</a>
</li>
```

I need to change the class of the `<ins>` tags for a specific `<li>`. 
I need to access the `<li>` id and then change the class of all `<ins>` tags found inside it

I would appreciate it if someone could show me the right way to do that.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: What specific ins item do you need to change?

Comment: @tanya: be sure to accept the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#toto ins").attr("class","className"); // all ins
$("#toto ins:eq(0)").attr("class","className"); // first ins
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add and remove classes for the `ins` tags like this, using jQuery:

```
$('#toto ins').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#toto ins").removeClass().addClass("yourClass")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#toto ins').attr('class', 'new-class');
```

Comment: `'#toto > ins'` won't work: in the example, one of the `<ins>`s is inside an `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `toggleClass` for this:

```
$("#toto ins").toggleClass("className");
```